# try to parse the log by using javascript, and nothing shown

Tags: javascript

I am quite new in Javascript, and I am trying to parse the log something like

```
2014-02-25T,ip='99.114.',rm=GET,rv=HTTP/1.1,rs=200,rt=0.787020,ru='/tag/febe1eab436e98eb4ed3711870496c91/st.js?l=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.michaels.com%%2Fon%2Fdemandware.store%2FSites-Michaels-Site%2Fdefault%2F-scrapbooking',cl=996,rr='http://www.michaels.com/videos/KBPP1Vm3075,default,pg.html?fdid=videos-scrapbooking',
```

I want to separate them by ',', and only show 'rr' attribute. Following is my code, and when I run it, there is nothing shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
<title>reading file</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var reader = new FileReader();

function readText(that){

    if(that.files && that.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {  
            var output=e.target.result;
            var str = output;
            var start =0;
            var end = 0;
            while (end<str.length){
                while (end<str.length && str.charAt(end)!=',') {
                    end++;
                }
                var stringLine="";
                if (end==str.length) {
                    stringLine = str.substring(start, str.length);
                }else {
                    stringLine = str.substring(start, end+1);
                }

                var signIndex=0;
                while (stringLine.charAt(signIndex)!='=') {
                    signIndex++;
                }
                var newSubString = stringLine.substring(0,signIndex);
                if (newSubString==="ip"){
                    document.write(stringLine);
                    document.write("<br />");
                }

                start=end+1;
                end=start;
            } 

        };//end onload()

        reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);

    }//end if html5 filelist support
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use `str.split(',')` instead of scanning the line character by character?

Comment: Did you check the error console of your web browser?

Comment: This is my first javascript code. So I just wrote the code firstly in Java, and change the code a little bit for javascript. I am not sure how to change a new line if I use split(','). Anyone could fix the code?